# Encoding issues with german Umlaute ä, ö, ü and ß in R

Tags: r, csv, encoding, import, special-characters

I work on a mac and I'm currently working with a large csv file (german language) that I import to R. Encoding for ä, ö, ü, and ß is fine in that CSV file. When I import it, however, things get messy for those letters.
ü becomes `<c3><bc>`,
ä becomes `<c3><a4>`
....

I tried to apply UTF-8 when importing: `df <- read.csv("file.csv", sep=";", encoding = "UTF-8")`Still it looks the same. Standard encoding is also set to UTF-8.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: try `readr::read_csv`

Comment: Are you sure you know what encoding was used in the raw file? What OS are you on? It's not necessarily the case that the file uses UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: @xwhitelight not working.

Comment: @MrFlick I'm on Catalina 10.15.4. It was originally an xlsx file that I changed a little and saved as UTF-8 csv file. That's the one I try to import

Comment: By `<c3><bc>`, do you mean those 8 characters, or the hex representation of 2 bytes?  Check the _byte_ length of the string.

Comment: @RickJames based on byte length, it must the hex representation.

Comment: Random notes on R:     Tool -> Global Options -> Code -> Saving and put UTF-8
   rs <- dbSendQuery(con, 'set character set "utf8"')
   rs <- dbSendQuery(con, 'SET NAMES utf8')


options(encoding = "UTF-8") at the top of my main script from which I call my package seems to fix the issue with having non-ascii characters in my package code.

read_chunk(lines = readLines("TestSpanishText.R", encoding = "UTF-8")) (also file())

Comment: @RickJames I don't really understand what you want me to do.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the CSV and use the save as function of Excel to transform it. Save the file as `CSV UTF-8 (Comma delimited)` (it is called `CSV UTF-8 (durch Trennzeichen getrennt)` in German). Import this file with `readr::read_csv('newfile.csv')`.